# In "делегация из 5 человек во главе с президентом", are 5 or 6 visitors meant?

Tags: словоупотребление, числительные

Got a business letter with this phrase followed by a list of 6 officials, sixth being a president. So I wonder whether it's me who always interpreted this phrase incorrectly (5 members total) or them (6 members)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is exactly why the words like "включительно", "включая" do exist - otherwise in some cases there is indeed a disambiguation. The answer to your question is that the phrase "делегация из N человек во главе с президентом" can mean either N or N+1.

To avoid such uncertainty one can say:

- Делегация из пяти человек **вместе** с президентом
- Делегация из пяти человек **и** президент
- Делегация из шести человек, **включая** президента
- Делегация из пяти человек, **не включая** президента

Comment: Вместо "не включая" в быту обычно говорят "не считая"

Comment: @PavelMayorov good point!

Answer (score 4):

It's them, and it doesn't look like an intuitive kind of mistake: by which I mean, it was likely caused by uninformed overthinking on the part of the person that wrote the letter.